# CodeIgniter MYSQLI get is different from

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, mysqli, codeigniter-3

Upgrading the CRUD file on a project(I didn't write it) from CI 1 to CI 3.  It seems to be working and pulling recordsets, but it's removing the limit feature at the very end.  Here is a sample of what's occuring. By my understanding the get_compiled_select() and get() should use the same Select String but it's not happening.  See below/Explanations please.

```
$this->db->limit($options['limit'], $options['offset']);
print($this->db->get_compiled_select());
$query = $this->db->get();  //Seems to be dropping limit.
print($this->db->last_query());
```

This results in:

```
SELECT * FROM `students` WHERE surname LIKE '%' ESCAPE '!' OR fname LIKE '%' ESCAPE '!' LIMIT 24
SELECT * FROM `students` WHERE surname LIKE '%' ESCAPE '!' OR fname LIKE '%' ESCAPE '!'
```

And it obviously returns all the records and iterates through them.  Not sure why these two would be so different. Anybody know why this is happening and how to fix it?

Comment: I'm fairly certain that get_compiled_select() clears *all* qb options so qb is ready for another query in a clear state.

Comment: That was it, just remarked out the get compiled and voila. Feeling kinda stupid on this one :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$this->db->get_compiled_select() By default resets Query Builder, You can try

```
$this->db->limit($options['limit'], $options['offset']);
print($this->db->get_compiled_select()); // Query Builer resets here
$query = $this->db->get('mytable',limit,offset);  //Seems to be dropping limit.
print($this->db->last_query());
```

or 
You can pass second parameter in get_compiled select as FALSE

```
$this->db->limit($options['limit'], $options['offset']);
print($this->db->get_compiled_select('MyTable',FALSE)); // 
$query = $this->db->get('mytable',limit,offset);  limit.
print($this->db->last_query());
```

Comment: Prior to this code they are using 


   $this->db->limit($options['limit'], $options['offset']);

Is this incorrect?

Comment: nope it isn't... @prasanna that's why its always a good idea to explain **how** this is different than the current code (functionally it isn't - or atleast - shouldn't be).

Comment: @Kevrone Yes. it is still. Remember get_compiled_select() resets query builed. if you dont wish it be then pass false in it.get_compiled_select('mytable', FALSE);

Comment: Haha Awesome.. resets query build is what killed me. A simple remark on the print fixed the problem (Hand to face emoji here).  Thanks Alex & prasanna